# ValueError: Button.background_down accept only str

Tags: python, kivy-language

I am getting the  `ValueError: Button.background_down accept only str` error when I launch my python kivy app, the issue resides in the .kv file. The program complain about this line: `background_down:  hex('#DCDCDC')`. I know what the error implies, I just don't know how to fix it. I have tried passing in the rgba value (for the sake of trying every way), but it didn't work.

I appreciate any response, cheers!

Comment: Just guessing, but does `background_down: "#DCDCDC"` work?

Comment: From the docs, it appears that `background_down` is supposed to be the URL of an image to display, not a color.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, No it doesn't.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, Oh.. Well then, how do I change the color that is displayed on pressing from blue to any other?

Comment: I suppose you could update the `background_color` in the `on_state` handler.

Comment: Or, just create some solid color bitmaps.  ImageMagick can do that pretty easily, or a simple Python script with PIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind button behavior to a background_color:

in kv lang:

```
Button:
    background_color: (1,0,1,1) if self.state == "normal" else (0,1,0,1)
```

(0,1,0,1) is the color when pressed, you can also do that color first and use if self.state == "down"  :)